# TensorFlow Input Layer automatically converts from float64 to int32?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I've been working on a model and I noticed that my input tensors are of datatype `tf.float64`, however my input layers require `tf.int32`, however everything works as expected. My question is, does the input layer:

```py
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,), name='in', dtype='int32')
```

Automatically convert a tensor defined by:

```py
element_spec = ({'in': tf.TensorSpec(shape=16, 5), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)})
```

Into the correct tensor datatype? Eg from `float64` to `int32`?

The full script is:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import TFAutoModel

bert = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')

input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(512,), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')
mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(512,), name='attention_mask', dtype='int32')

embeddings = bert.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=mask)[1]
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(embeddings)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='outputs')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids, mask], outputs=y)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5, decay=1e-6)
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
acc = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[acc])

element_spec = ({'input_ids': tf.TensorSpec(shape=(16, 512), dtype=tf.float64, name=None),
                 'attention_mask': tf.TensorSpec(shape=(16, 512), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)},
                tf.TensorSpec(shape=(16, 5), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))

train_ds = tf.data.experimental.load('train', element_spec=element_spec)
val_ds = tf.data.experimental.load('val', element_spec=element_spec)

history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=3
)
```

When I check the `element_spec` of the dataset being loaded from file (before it is saved to file) I get:

```py
tf.data.experimental.save(train_ds, 'train')
tf.data.experimental.save(val_ds, 'val')

print(train_ds.element_spec)
>> ({'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(16, 512), dtype=tf.float64, name=None),
>>   'attention_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(16, 512), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)},
>>  TensorSpec(shape=(16, 5), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))
```

Comment: It shouldn't. What's the errro?

Comment: @M.Innat I don't get any error, which is why I'm confused, as the types don't seem to align, I've added more code and info